# Как отправить сообщение по telegram id исходя из результата проверки в функции другого бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Суть такова, человек из первого бота оставляет заявку в базу данных, когда из другого бота эта заявка одобрена мне нужно сообщить об этом человеку в первом боте, простым bot.send_message не выйдет потому что во втором боту человека нету. Тоесть мне нужно из одного бота запустить функцию в другом боте

Answer (score 0):

Одно из простых решений, вручную отправлять запрос на Telegram-сервер от имени первого бота:

```py
token = "abc123def"  # Токен первого бота
text = "Вам поступил новый ответ"
user_id = 123456  # ID юзера первого бота

url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={user_id}&text={text}"

requests.get(url)
```